# How to change file type labels in Explorer using 3rd-party-programs or hacks inside Windows

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I want to do this experiment: Change the file type label to something else.

### Example:

Lets say there is a "APK" file on the computer. Instead of the file type column saying "APK File" I want to say something like, "Android Installer File" without assigning an application.

I tried regedit but it is complicated because there is no string inside the folder for the label.

It would also be nice to change the icon of the file if it has that file format, instead of that paper folded a little.

Answer (score 4):

File-type names are described in the registry.

For example on my computer, `.jpg` files are handled by
`paint.net` and the name can be found and changed in the
registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\paint.net.1`.

However, if no description exists for the `.apk` file extension,
meaning it has not been associated with a program, then Explorer
will issue a generic message saying "APK file", and this message
cannot be changed, since it's generated on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

Open registry editor (regedit).
Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, then find subkey ".apk". Check its default value, it's the name of another key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, go into that key. The default value in that key should be the label.

I don't have APK, but if I go to .txt, the default is "textfile", and when I go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\textfile, the default value is "Text Document". That's the label.

Some references: [How to Register a File Type for a New Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-register-a-file-type-for-a-new-application)
[File Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-file-types)

Comment: Any 3rd party apps?

Comment: I'm not aware of a 3rd party app to edit those labels, outside of all the various registry editor.